# make an input button to enforce the required attribute option on an input text field

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input button related to a file input such that when a button is clicked the file input function gets triggered. So, the button works as an upload button knowing that the file input is hidden. The button has a text value after selecting a file and the button take the name of the chosen file as a new text value.

My question is how to make the upload button enforce the **required** attribute option on the file upload text field when the file is not chosen.

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    <input type="file" class="file-upload" style="display: none;">
    <button type="button" class="file-button">Upload File</button>
    <input required type="text" placeholder="type here">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="go_button" class="button">
</form>

<script>
    const fileUpload = document.querySelector('.file-upload')
    const fileButton = document.querySelector('.file-button')

    // This function for the Upload file
    fileButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        fileUpload.click()
    })

    fileUpload.addEventListener("change", function(){
        if (fileUpload.value){
            fileButton.innerHTML = fileUpload.value
        } else {
            fileButton.innerHTML = "Upload File"
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by a required button?

Comment: i mean when i submit without choosing a file a message will appear saying (Please felect a file)

Comment: if you run my code and you submit without filling a text in the text input a message will appear saying (Please fill out this field), that's what i want for my button

Comment: It's the input text field that is required not the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the submit event and check the value of the upload

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.onsubmit = function(event) {
  if (!fileUpload.value) {
    alert('Please select a file');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/ayeletdn/pen/XLwevZ?editors=1011)

Comment: thank you so much for the reply but using alerts it's just not convenient for me, and also if possible i would prefer not to go through javascript but i really appreciate the effort

Comment: You can change the alert to anything else such as setting some error message in the body.

Comment: If you set `required` attribute on the input field, you'll prevent the form from submitting without a file - but the user will not see any error message, as the field is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Let me get you clear, You want the required option on the input field to be enforced when you hit the upload button just as when you hit the submit button.

By default, only inputs and buttons of type `submit` can enforce the required option on text input fields. If you want the required option enforced on your upload button **without using javascript** you must give it a type of `submit` like this:

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    <input type="file" class="file-upload" style="display: none;">
    <button type="submit" class="file-button">Upload File</button>
    <input required type="text" placeholder="type here">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="go_button" class="button">
</form>
```

You can see it working on the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/udochify/tfn93685/3/).

If you do this, you would now have two buttons that submits the form and both of them will require that the text input be filled before a submit.

One way to ensure that only one button submits the form is to make the file upload asynchronous and prevent the default submit behaviour on the upload button while still enforcing the required option on the associated text field.

Comment: Thank you very much i wasn't aware that only inputs and buttons of type submit can enforce the required option , you were very helpful i really appreciate it.